# Unable to check for msg.value

Tags: contract-development, transactions, myetherwallet, ganache

Here is my code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TRY{  
    uint public temp=0;  
    function transfer_ether() public payable{  
        require(msg.value>=60);  
        temp=60;  
        msg.sender.transfer(msg.value-60);  
    }  
    function to_contract() public payable {  
        uint a=temp;  
        temp=0;  
        msg.sender.transfer(a);  
    }  
}
```

I deployed this code on test network on MyEtherWallet using Ganache.
Even when I enter a value less than 60.. it still doesn't revert as specified in the condition.
I cannot understood why is it happening.It would be helpful if someone explains the problem.

The solution to this problem:
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TRY{

```
uint public temp=0;
uint public b=0;

function transfer_ether() public payable{
   require(msg.value>=60 ether);
        temp=msg.value;
         b=temp-(60 ether);
        temp=60 ether;
       msg.sender.transfer(b );
}

function to_contract() public payable {
    uint a=temp;
    temp=0;
    msg.sender.transfer(a);
}
```

}

Comment: how are you sending the value to the contract? If is via code just update your question, if not please consider that the value is expressed in wei not in ether

Comment: how to convert it to ether? in code.

Comment: just change your condition `require(msg.value >= 60 ether)`

Comment: Moreover, you should use > instead of >= , because sending 0 ether is useless.